# Android custom Layout in FRAGMENT based on baseAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to use custom `ListView` in extends from `ListFragment` class. After create new subClass extends from `BaseAdapter` into current class and set layout to that I get `... has stopped` error.

list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/txt2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ResivedSMS.java :

```
public class ResivedSMS extends ListFragment {
    private String testArray1[];
    private String testArray2[];
    private ListView listFragment;

    public ResivedSMS() {

        testArray1 = new String[] {
                "1111111111",
                "2222222222",
                "3333333333",
                "4444444444",
                "5555555555",
                "6666666666",
        };
        testArray1 = new String[] {
                "AAAAA",
                "BBBBB",
                "CCCCC",
                "DDDDD",
                "FFFFF",
                "GGGGG",
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        listFragment = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        ViewResivedSMSDetailes customListView = new ViewResivedSMSDetailes(getActivity(),testArray1,testArray2);
        listFragment.
                setAdapter( customListView );

        return listFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    class ViewResivedSMSDetailes extends BaseAdapter
    {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private String[] values1;
        private String[] values2;
        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txt1;
            TextView txt2;
        }

        public ViewResivedSMSDetailes(Context context,String[] values1,String[] values2)
        {

            this.values1=values1;
            this.values2=values2;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return values1.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int index) {
            return values1[index];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if(convertView ==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null);
                holder.txt1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                holder.txt2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.txt1.setText(values1[position]);
            holder.txt2.setText(values2[position]);

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

logcat Result:

```
08-24 10:33:34.675      349-349/ir.tsms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
            at ir.tsms.ResivedSMS.onCreateView(ResivedSMS.java:50)
```

ResivedSMS.java:50 is:

```
listFragment = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
```

Whats my code problem and how to resolved Thanks?

Comment: You are not really creating a custom view here. Rather, you are creating a fragment that displays a list view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
```

You are inflating a `LinearLayout` not a `ListView` thus giving you `ClassCastException`

**solution:**

Since you are using `ListFragment` you can directly set the adapter, since `ListFragment` has its own default `ListView`. Set the adapter in the `onCreate` Method.

**sample:**

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewResivedSMSDetailes customListView = new ViewResivedSMSDetailes(getActivity(),testArray1,testArray2);
        setListAdapter( customListView ); //call the method if listFragment

    }
```

Comment: in `onCreate` function i have only this code:`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` after change it with your solution i get error for `setAdapter`: `can not resolve method setAdapter` and in `onCreateView` function must be have only: `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` ???

Comment: @TuxWorld sorry it supposed to be `setListAdapter`